# SharePoint 2013 Development on Surface Pro 3

Tags: 2013, development

I am considering buying a Surface Pro 3 i7 8gb with 512gb storage and I am thinking of using it for development.

I am wondering if anyone here has used their Surface for SharePoint 2013 development.

I mean run a VM with SharePoint 2013 on Windows 2008 R2 Server with Visual Studio installed?

Comment: I doubt you can run such large VM on it. May be this blog can help http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2014/06/23/complete-surface-pro-3-review-3-days-later.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage and processor should be no problem. Your virtual mashine will take about 50-80 GB of storage). But the main problem is RAM. Normally you can give about 6 GB of RAM to virtual machine. SharePoint 2013 requires minimum 8 GB of RAM. If you give less that 8 GB of RAM to your VM, SharePoint 2013 server runs quite slow.
On the other hand, you can tune you SharePoint configuration and to turn off service applications you do not need, like Search. 
Also if you will use SharePoint 2013 Foundation it will run without any problem, because it uses much less resources.

You can check Microsoft recommendations [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#MinimumRecDev).

Also keep in mind that, if you turn on Hyper-V on Surface you will not be able to use InstantGo, feature according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Surface_Pro_3#InstantGo)

Answer (score 0):

Last year, I bought the Surface Pro 3 for exactly the same reason. It was an i5/8GB RAM/256GB SSD model. The i7 CPU won't buy you much more. The biggest bottle neck was the RAM. Running SQL Server, SP, etc...just kills the Surface. It'll run, but not run well. It also depends on the services running, but honestly, 8GB is too little.

Comment: I have been using my Surface Pro 3 i7 8GB 512GB for 8 months now, I had no performance issue running SharePoint in VirtualBox with allocated memory of 5-6GB Ram. I also using as my dedicated development machine for home and work.

So the SP4 with 16GB of RAM is out, I am considering buy this one, but then the price is really expensive. But has anyone here bought a SP4 and used it for general and SharePoint development?

Answer (score 0):

I think the 16GB will do nicely. When I had the SP3, my biggest problem was the fan running constantly, the heat, and the throttling when running an SP VM. On my full blown desktop machine I'm able to run s standalone farm rather decently with 8GB of RAM and 4 cores allocated to it. YMMV.

Comment: I know what you mean, I experienced exactly the same thing as you with the Surface Pro 3.